# javascript iterator and generator

Tags: javascript

I have written below code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function testGenerator()
{
yield "first";
document.write("step1");
yield "second";
document.write("step2");
yield "third";
 document.write("step3");
 }
 var g = testGenerator();
document.write(g.next());
document.write(g.next());
 </script>
```

My desired output: step1step2
But the above code show nothing on my html. Could any one help me to figure out what the mistake I have done here.

Thanks

Comment: `yield` is not supported in ES5. Generators will be available in ES6 (which probably takes a long time to be picked up by browsers...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generators/iterators are currently [only supported by Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/IndexedDB/Using_IndexedDB/Using_JavaScript_Generators_in_Firefox), and to use them you need to change your script tag's `type` attribute to `"text/javascript;version=1.7"`.